# Value not saving in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array which have this structure:

```
$queues[n] Array (
[id] => integer
[idClient] => integer
[name] => string
[people] => integer )
```

Which is populated with:

```
$query = "SELECT clients.idClient AS 'idClient', queues.idQueue AS 'idQueue', queues.name AS 'name' FROM clients, queues WHERE clients.idClient = queues.client";
    $queues = null;

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result){
        while ($queue = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $queues[] = array ("idClient" => $queue['idClient'], "id" => $queue['idQueue'], "name" => $queue['name'], "people" => 0);
        }
    }
```

Each 'n' value match a queue from Database and people, by default is set to 0.

After populating the array I query the database again with each queue to other table to obtain the number of people in queue with a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM peoplequeued WHERE queue ='".$queue['name']."'
```

And then:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($result){
            $num_people = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $queue['people'] = $num_people[0];
        }
```

And something strange happens here. If I echo the $queue['people'] in the foreach, it shows fine the value it got but if I preview the full array before returning it, it's back to 0.

What could be happening?

Comment: Just a hint: If you have wrong code, don't write here what you see as the right code. Just copy/paste the whole relevant sequence. There may be traps you didn't notice, and didn't place them here. The other hint: Do it all in one single query.

Comment: As a side note: I recommend looking into PDO and prepared statements.  Besides a performance gain you will also gain a lot in recurity. The query you show is typically vounerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: How do you get that `$queue` variable?

Comment: @AlexanderMP there is no more code to paste, just foreachs. @Arend this code can't be injected since you aren't able to change in anyways, the query.

Comment: @Antonio, that's exactly my point. Those `foreach` statements may be the actual cause, but we are unable to determine that because we can't see them. You admitted you had a mistake in your code, but didn't let us figure out where this error is.

Comment: Do you see the answers? They all point at the `foreach` statement that you didn't include in your code :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you're looping through `$queues` with `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach ( $queues as $queue ) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result){
        $num_people = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $queue['people'] = $num_people[0];
    }
}
```

If so, there's no "link" between `$queue` and `$queues[$n]`, i.e., by modifying `$queue`, you do NOT modify `$queues`.

If this is the case, you should either use `$queue` as reference variable, or modify `$queues[$n]` with `$n` being an index.

```
foreach ( $queues as &$queue ) { // add & so $queue is a reference to an element in $queues
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result){
        $num_people = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $queue['people'] = $num_people[0];
    }
}
unset($queue); // drop the reference, otherwise you might have unexpected results after modifying $queue outside the loop
```

... or ...

```
foreach ( $queues as $n => $queue ) { // store index of "current" element in $n
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result){
        $num_people = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $queues[$n]['people'] = $num_people[0]; // change $queue to $queues[$n]
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, I would advise you to think about getting all data in a single statement. It looks like something like this might work for you:

```
select
    baseTable.id,
    baseTable.idClient,
    baseTable.name,
    peopleCount.count as people
from
    baseTable
    left join (
        select
            count(*) as count,
            queue
        from
            peoplequeued
        group by
            queue
    ) as peopleCount on peopleCount.queue = baseTable.name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I thought they were linked, that is not a copy but a pointer. Thanks :D

Comment: They are linked, if you add `&` before the variable. But be careful with this - variable stays defined and linked to the last element of an array, if you do not `unset()` it after the loop. Also, I have updated my answer with an alternative solution that would allow you to get rid of multiple queries - doing DB queries in a loop is very bad practice.

Comment: I have to try and adapt it because it's not working with this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count', cola FROM relcolaext GROUP BY cola)" but thanks for your help. It's always good to improve the code and performance.

Comment: I created `baseTable` table that consists of `id`, `idClient` and `name` columns and `peoplequeued` table that consists of `id`, `queue` and `name` fields. With such tables, that query works without any syntax error. If you have `where` clause, be sure to write it *after* the join, i.e., `select ... from some_source left join another_source where ...`. Also, I'd advise to change `FROM clients, queues WHERE clients.idClient = queues.client` part to a `join`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're probably using a `foreach` loop to cycle through your `$queues` array, like this:

```
foreach($queues as $queue) {

}
```

Each `$queue` variable generated is a copy, and changes to it aren't saved to the `$queues` variable. To save changes as you're intending, you need to do something like:

```
foreach($queues as $k => $queue) {
    $queue['people'] = 10;
    $queues[$k] = $queue;
    // or, more efficiently...
    $queues[$k]['people'] = 10;
}
```

In PHP5 you can also reference. See http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. I didn't know that of PHP